# How can I override event action for a Universal Analytics tag in a server-side GTM container that receives its hits from a GA4 tag?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

This is my situation:

- A client-side GTM container contains a GA4 tag that sends its events to a server-side container containing `event_category`, `event_action`, `event_label` and `non_interaction` event parameters
- A GA4 client in that server-side container that receives these events
- A Universal Analytics tag (among others) in that server-side container that forwards the events

`event_category`, `event_label` and `non_interaction` are correctly translated to `ec`, `el` and `ni` in the outgoing HTTP request, but somehow `event_action` isn’t. `ea` is populated with the value of `event` instead.

I’ve tried explicitly creating an Event Data variable for `event_action` and mapping that to `event_action` in the server-side UA tag, but that didn’t change anything.

So, how can I override event action for a Universal Analytics tag in a server-side GTM container that receives its hits from a GA4 tag?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: It looks like you can override any of the parameters of the outgoing HTTP request by adding `x-ga-mp1-` plus the parameter to “Override Fields to Set” in the server-side Universal Analytics tag. So in my case that means `x-ga-mp1-ea` and a couple more:

[image: Universal Analytics tag in a server-side GTM container]

(Figured this out when [trying to add a custom dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67704089/1913230).)