# How can I add custom dimensions to a Universal Analytics tag in a server-side GTM container that receives its hits from a GA4 tag?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

This is my situation:

- A client-side GTM container contains a GA4 tag that sends its hits to a server-side container containing custom event parameters, e.g. `page_type`
- A GA4 client in that server-side container that receives these hits
- A Universal Analytics tag (among others) in that server-side container that forwards the hits

How can I add the value of `page_type` to the Universal Analytics tag as a custom dimension?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can use `x-ga-mp1-cd1` in the “Override Fields to Set” to achieve this, as mentioned [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/server-side-tagging-google-tag-manager/) by Simo Ahava.